# How to query # of instances of random words

Tags: sql, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have a table that has a column filled with data like the following:

["internal"]

["internal"]

["internal"]

["External"]

["Learning"]

["Learning"]

["internal"]

["Learning"]

["Education"]

["Education"]

["Learning"]

["Learning"]

["new product"]

["random information"]

It is not always predictable what will go in that column.  But I need to run a report with a count for each unique "phrase" in that column.

I would love to do something like:

```
=QUERY(A3:O16, "select J, counta(J) group by J label count(J) 'Number of times phrase appears'")
```

Is there a way to make a "smart query" without knowing ahead of time what will be in that column?

Comment: It would be very complicated if google could predict the future, so as long as you can't define rules, what goes where, you must do it by yourself

Comment: [Here](https://www.statology.org/google-sheets-query-group-by/) they show an example of grouping entries by a column's value and generating an average but you could try the same and get the count instead

Comment: as @Portal suggested. i would add yo lowerkey when groping by , so it will eliminate duplicates.
...group by LOWER(J)...

Comment: I wasn't smooch asking them to predict the future.  I was hoping there was a way to collect the data in a column and then process it in one query.
But I think that these answers give me a way to proceed.  Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

you're very close with your guess with the query:

=QUERY(A3:O16, "select J, count(J) group by J label count(J) 'Number of times phrase appears'")

you'd written ... "counta(J)" ... by mistake i think?